# Как использовать promise на vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Фрагмент моего кода, если не использовать промис, то не удается вытащить данные корректно

```
   Promise((resolve) => {     
                fetch('/currentDir1',{
                    method: 'POST',
                    mode: 'cors',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',                    
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(elem)                
                    })
                    .then(response => response.json())    
                    .then(json => this.helper = json)
                    .then(json =>  this.$emit("newvalue", json)) 
                    console.log("helper");
                    console.log(this.helper);
                    resolve("result");
             });
```

Обработчик со стороны сервера

```
router.post('/currentDir1',(req, res) =>{  
    console.log("POST");
    
    let body = "";   
    let pathToFile = "";
    req.on("data", function (data) {
        body += data;
    });
    req.on("end", function(currentData) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(body));
        currentData = JSON.parse(body);
        

        if(currentData.sizeOrType === "<папка>"){
            let dir = currentData.dir + currentData.fileName;
            // dir = "C:\\totalcmd";
            console.log(dir);                
            if(currentData.whichScreen){
                foo(dir, './data/firstScreen.json');
                pathToFile = './data/firstScreen.json';
                res.sendFile(path.resolve('./data/firstScreen.json'));
            }else{
                console.log('aaaa');
                Foo(dir, './data/secondScreen.json');
                pathToFile = './data/firstScreen.json';
                res.sendFile(path.resolve('./data/secondScreen.json'));
                
            }        
        }
        // res.json({ message: 'goodbye'})   
        res.json(path.resolve(pathToFile));     
    });        
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(pathToFile));
})
```

Comment: А в чем у вас проблема собственно? Насколько я знаю, использование Promise во Vue ничем не отличается от стандартного использования.
Можете создать async метод и в нем сделать все что вам нужно через async/await.

Comment: @dmitriy_vlz так вот и я не понимаю как. Не понимаю как это должно быть

Comment: а что значит не использовать промис?

Comment: @Komdosh мне нужно передать переменную helper в родительский компонент. Но происходит так, что она не получает нужное значение, я решил, что дело в том, что она просто не дожидается ответа от сервера, а сразу отправляет переменную.

Answer (score 0):

ну я попробовал "на коленке" накидать, попробуй.

```
 async nameOfMethod(){
  const responce = await  fetch('/currentDir1',{
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',                    
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(elem)                
    });
  
    const json = await responce.json()
    this.helper = json
    this.$emit("newvalue", json)
}
```

Comment: сейчас попробу. я точно могу использовать async внутри раздела methods  на vue?

Comment: кажется он не позволяет вставлять функцию внутрь себя

Comment: В методах вы объявляете функции, конечно же там можно пользоваться async/await

Comment: Все так же не удается получить данные от сервера .....

Comment: А у тебя сам fetch вообще что-то возвращает? МБ promise тут вообще не прич ем)

Comment: Добавил код обработчика запроса к вопросы, посмотри, плиз

Comment: Мне твой роут не даст ничего)
Просто console.log(responce) после fetch сделай и посмотри, что тебе вообще с сервера приходит и приходил ли что-то вообще.